# Story Identification: A late 1990s/early 2000s graphic novel about vampires?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, vampire, graphic-novel

When I was a kid in the 1990s (possibly early 2000s) I remember checking out this graphic novel from my local library (in CA, USA) several times. It was volume 1 and the back cover said volume 2 was out now, but I never read it.

The protagonist was an awkward blonde teenage girl with glasses; she was a huge history buff/nerd and didn't have any friends, except this one guy that she had a crush on. She was especially obsessed with the history of the small town she lived in with her aunt. One detail I remember is the crush using the phrase "same bat time, same bat channel" when saying goodbye to her. I didn't know at the time that it was a TV reference, so it just seemed like a weird thing to say.

The plot is that a mysterious stranger moves into the historic mansion previously owned by the town's founder. The mysterious stranger is actually a vampire, and also the aforementioned founder of the town. They strike up a friendship. The climax is when another (evil) vampire shows up and the two vampires fight; during the fight, she also gets turned into a vampire to assist. The good vampire wins, but does not survive. In the end, he leaves everything to her in his will, so now she and her aunt live in a big mansion, and she makes friends at school and starts dating her crush. And she's a vampire.

No, it wasn't well written, but I just can't remember the name and I'd like to know! Do you know?

Comment: Adults in the 90s who grew up in the 70s and 80s would have been able to watch the Batman TV show, which featured a voice over/narrator who would end most episodes by saying something like, "Tune in next week for the exciting conclusion - Same Bat-time, same Bat-channel!" This is the same TV show that has the "na-na-na-na na-na-na-na Bat-man!" theme song.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yes, I know that now. At the time it struck me as very out of place since none of the other characters made pop culture references, much less quoted TV shows from the sixties.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be *[Confessions of a Teenage Vampire](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0590104667)* by  Terry M. West, released in 1997?

[image: Cover of Confessions of a Teenage Vampire depicting a blonde teenage girl with glasses]

> Wondering about Aaron Lemachard II, the founder of her New England town, Lily Jordon discovers that he is a vampire who has lived for nearly four hundred years and has chosen her to join the world of the undead. Original.

You can find a better recap [here](https://www.pointhorror.com/5269/confessions-of-a-teenage-vampire-the-turning-by-west-and-ellis/) (albeit with some spoilers) that mention her interest in history, her aunt, Sang's attack, her turning, and LeMarchand leaving everything to her in his will at the end of the first book (they recap the second book [here](https://www.pointhorror.com/5806/confessions-of-a-teenage-vampire-zombie-saturday-night-by-west-and-ellis/)).

Found with a search for `"graphic novel" vampire town founder`

Comment: Yes that's it! Thank you. Haha - the title is so generic I'm surprised I didn't find it in my prior searches.